# Drools: why indexOf() does not work in LHS?

Tags: drools

Why can't I use indexOf() to look for index of specific object in List in `when`?
Here is the example. Once I comment out `list.indexOf($o) > 0`, rule executes and index shows correct in `then` section.

```
declare Seq
list: List
end

rule "initSeq"
when
    $p: ObjectWrapper (
       ...
    )
    $list: List () from collect (ObjectWrapper (...))
    not initSeq (....)
then
    Seq w = new Seq ();
    w.setList($list);
end

rule "doSeq"
when:
    $o: ObjectWrapper (
       ...
    )
    $rr: Seq (
       ...
       list.indexOf($o) > 0
    )
then:
    DroolsLogger.debug ("index: " + $rr.getList().indexOf($o));
end
```

Comment: I've been working with drools recently and I noticed there are only a couple of standard Java methods that properly work in the when clause. indexOf is probably one of those that doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that indexOf() works in LHS.
I still do not understand the reason why it is was not working for me before, but now I have working rule with indexOf in LHS.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can remove `list.indexOf($o) > 0` filter from the pattern and add a new condition as
`eval($rr.getList().indexOf($o) > 0)` in the when part of the rule.